# discord py - slow performance on message delete (multiple servers)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, mysql-python

I have a problem. I own a global-chat, that shares user messages across over 100+ servers. All messages have a one-time code to delete this message on every server.

But my bot takes over 2 hours to delete one message that's really awful and bad if someone spams an insult. So I'm asking how I can speed up my code, so he can delete the message very fast from all servers.

My code is a discord command, that deletes specific messages (every message contains a one-time code and is saved in the database) on every server where the bot is.

**Picture of how the messages are saved in the database:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/54VTc.png
`messageID` = Original message id from the message author.
`code` = one-time code for every message.
`ids` = all other message ids, which contains the same one-time code.
`time` = delete the row at this time, to delete very old messages from the database, to clear things up.

**Picture of how my "servers"-table is saved in DB:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNoCJ.png
`guildID` = guildid from the specific server.
`channelID` = channel where the bot posts his messages.

And that's my code for the delete message command:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["delmsg", "deletemessage", "msgdelete", "del"])
    async def delete(ctx, code=None):
        guild = bot.get_guild(616655040614236160)
        member = guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
        role2 = guild.get_role(792894127972155393)  # Admin
        role3 = guild.get_role(792894172829974529)  # Mod
     
        if role2 in member.roles or role3 in member.roles:
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="**",
                user="**",
                password="**",
                database="global-bot"
            )
     
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
     
            mycursor.execute(
                f"SELECT * FROM messeges WHERE code = '{code}'")
            myresult3 = mycursor.fetchall()
            if myresult3:
                await ctx.message.delete()
                await ctx.send('start deleting message..', delete_after=15)
                mycursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM servers")  ##########
                myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
                ids = myresult3[0][2].split(" ")
                for x in ids:
                    for server in myresult:
                        try:
                            x1 = [server]
                            channel = bot.get_channel(int(x1[0][1]))
                            msg = await channel.fetch_message(int(x))
                            await msg.delete()
                        except:
                            pass
                for server in myresult:
                    try:
                        x1 = [server]
                        channel = bot.get_channel(int(x1[0][1]))
                        msg = await channel.fetch_message(myresult3[0][0])
                        await msg.delete()
                    except:
                        pass
                channel2 = bot.get_channel(794269462848077845)
                await ctx.send(f"message with code {code} was deleted", delete_after=15)
                await channel2.send(embed=embed2)
    
    
                sql = f"DELETE FROM messeges WHERE code = '{code}'" # This line here is to delete the row with the used code in the delete command, for let my bot regenerate it and use it in a different message sometime.
                mycursor.execute(sql)
                mydb.commit()
     
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"message with one-time code `{code}` could not be deleted! Maybe you had a typo or the code doesnt exist.", delete_after=15)
                await ctx.message.delete()
        else:
            await ctx.send("not enough rights")
```

Comment: Is the issue that the bot can't delete it from all of the server's fast? Or that it lags & doesn't delete the first message after 2 hours

Comment: the bot can't delete it from all of the server's fast.

Comment: Would you be able to be more descriptive with your variable name? E.g. What is `x` and `xx`

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code for a while, I realised that this nested loop here is wildly inefficient:

```
for x in ids:
    for server in myresult:
        try:
           x1 = [server]
           channel = bot.get_channel(int(x1[0][1]))
           msg = await channel.fetch_message(int(x))
           await msg.delete()
         except:
           pass
```

This is because the program is wasting a huge amount of time trying to match the message id to the correct server. Instead of having the program do this, I highly suggest you store a foreign key in the form of the guild's id with a message when it's posted by your bot and added to the db.

This will allow you to remove the nested loop and only loop by message id, as you'll already have the corresponding guild id for each message.

Comment: How would that look? I'm confused with `you store a foreign key in the form of the guild's id with a message when it's posted by your bot and added to the db.`.

Comment: That's the way how I save the messages into my table: https://pastebin.com/v6LNEf1W

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp  <- Guide to foreign keys. I'm implying that you should have an extra column on your messages database that contains the guild id which corresponds to that message.

Comment: So I must add guildID to the messages database table as a column? And then?

Comment: and then you incorporate it into your code. So instead of wasting lots of time trying to match the message id to the correct server, you can just loop through each message, using the guildid from the database to delete the message from that specific guild. This removes the nested loop.

Comment: Second.. Wouldn't remove the loop and use guildID only delete the message from 1 guild and not from all?